# Plotly express doesn't load and refuse to connect

Tags: python, plotly

I have this simple program that should display a pie chart, but whenever I run the program, it opens a page on Chrome and just keeps loading without any display, and sometimes it refuses to connect. How do I solve this?

P.S.: I would like to use it offline, and I'm running it using cmd on windows10

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px


def graph(dataframe):
    figure0 = px.pie(dataframe, values=dataframe['POPULATION'], names=dataframe['CONTINENT'])
    figure0.show()


df = pd.DataFrame({'POPULATION': [60, 17, 9, 13, 1], 'CONTINENT': ['Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Americas', 'Oceania']})

graph(df)
```

Comment: I have moved your answer to a separate answer. Let me know if you want to post it yourself, then I'll remove mine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this answer from the OPs question. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555/316262).</sub>

---

#### Answer provided by [g_odim_3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15878933/g-odim-3):

So instead of `figure0.show()`, I used `figure0.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)` and it worked:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px


def graph(dataframe):
    figure0 = px.pie(dataframe, values=dataframe['POPULATION'], names=dataframe['CONTINENT'], title='Global Population')
#   figure0.show()
    figure0.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)


df = pd.DataFrame({'POPULATION':[60, 17, 9, 13, 1], 'CONTINENT':['Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Americas', 'Oceania']})

graph(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a version issue.

It's a long time since you needed an internet connection to build Plotly figures. Follow the instructions [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/) on how to upgrade your system. I've tried your exact code on my end at it produces the following plot:

[image]

I'm on **Plotly 5.2.2**. Run `import plotly` and `plotly.__version__` to check the version on your end.

Comment: I'm on version 5.2.2 too and installed using: pip3 install plotly

Comment: I'm running plotly 5.16.1 and have the same issue that g_odim_3 initially reported. Changing from .show(), to .write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True) fixed the issue for me.